# Selecting the right header file VSCODE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have multiple header files with the same name at different locations. How can I select the right header file when using #include in VScode?

The picture below show that multiple sources are available. VScode c++ multiple headers with same name:

[image]

Comment: The compiler and toolchain will take care of that, just put the correct header name. did you see any compiler error after compiling?

Comment: I did not see any error and I was wondering if it is because all the headers are very similar in content. Is there no way I can select the source of the header file manually? For example, for the WiFi.h the lightbulb appeared and I was able to select the source. But it has not shown again since then.